# Spring boot JPA OneToMany relationship - create related object if not exist

Tags: java, spring, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Say I have a oneToMany relationship between `Person` and `Job`. Each person has only one job, while a job has many persons.

I have a controller which calls the service which calls the repository that will execute the queries.

here they are:

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin()
@RequestMapping(path = "api/person")
public class PersonController {
    private final PersonService personService;
    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person storePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return this.personService.storePerson(person);
    }
    //...more code is also here
}

@Service
public class PersonService {
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired
    public PersonService(PersonRepository personRepository, CountryRepository countryRepository,
            JobRepository jobRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository, HairColorRepository hairColorRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public Person storePerson(Person person) {
        return this.personRepository.save(person);
    }
    //...more code is also here
}

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

Now the models and the way I define the relationship between them. I can code this in two ways.

**Senario 1:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Job.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
    private Job job;
    
    // ...getters and setters, constructors, toString(), etc are here
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class Job {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "job", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Person> persons;
    // ...getters and setters, constructors, toString(), etc are here
}
```

I use postman to insert records into this database.
I send a `POST` request and this is the body:

**First Json**

```json
{
    "name": "James",
    "job": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Doctor"
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, because it creates the person, it also creates a new job that DID NOT EXIST in the database, and also creates the relationship between the two.
But on second request, I want to *reuse* the Job. So I make this request:

**Second Json**

```json
{
    "name": "David",
    "job": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Doctor"
    }
}
```

Here I get an Exception:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-05T11:20:41.037+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "detached entity passed to persist: ir.arm.archiver.job.Job; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ir.arm.archiver.job.Job",
    "path": "/api/person"
}
```

**Senario2**

If I change the `Cascade` values in the relationship annotations a bit, I get the exact opposite results. If in `Person.java` I change the annotations for the `private Job job` field to use `Cascade.MERGE` like this:

```java
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Job.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
    private Job job;
```

Then, when I pass the *First Json*, this time, I get an exception:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-05T11:36:17.854+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ir.arm.archiver.person.Person.job -> ir.arm.archiver.job.Job; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : ir.arm.archiver.person.Person.job -> ir.arm.archiver.job.Job",
    "path": "/api/person"
}
```

BUT, if I create the job record myself in the database, and then I execute the request with the *Second Json*, it will work, and create the person with the relationship to the existing job record.

Now my question is:

How Can I combine the two? I want the JPA to do both.
Is there any way, to be able to pass both jsons and the jpa automatically creates the job, if the `Id` is null, and fetch and reuse it if it has `Id`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. Remove `cascade` attribute for Job member variable of Person Entity. JPA is combining both and also reusing the existing job from database.

Update Person Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Job.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
    private Job job;
    
    // ...getters and setters, constructors, toString(), etc are here
}
```

Output (In DB Person Table) :

[image]

Job Table :

[image]

Comment: What about the job pojo? Did you remove the cascade there also? 
**arm** -- You didn't share the code how you are saving the object and in what order these two objects are save in code for futher analysis

Comment: @SaranrajGunabalan No change is needed in Job pojo. That's why I didn't include it.